# Uploading SpagoBI OLAP template on SpagoBI server

Tags: spagobi

I've created the OLAP template following all the steps correctly in the SpagoBI studio. While uploading the XML template, I'm getting the following exception:

```
it.eng.spagobi.sdk.exceptions.SDKException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the xml produced by the Studio with a text editor you may probably notice that the hasAll tag is uncorrectly generated. If this is the problem you are facing, it's a known bug. You can edit the xml manually and then redeploy the template or wait for the patch to be published.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how must be the hasAll tag i.e; what is the correct way to use hasAll tag?

Comment: Thanks man! as you said, there was bug in xml file. I corrected it, and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases editing  `hasAll="` in your template.xml to `hasAll="true"` should work, but in my project editing xml file didnt help. Any other ideas how to solve it?